# Flutter plugins already installed but displaying not installed

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to install Flutter in Android Studio. I have installed flutter and dart plugins in Android Studio and I have also downloaded the flutter sdk and set the path.

But when I am running Flutter Doctor in the terminal it displays:
Flutter plugins not installed
Dart plugins not installed

Following is the image of the error:

[image]

I also tried uninstalling the flutter and dart plugins and re install them, but still getting the same error.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using android studio 4.1, then it's likely bug of the Android Studio or the flutter itself (you can read this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986)) as the plugins path may be changed in android studio 4.1.

For a temporary solution, you can use flutter `dev channel` that contains a fix for the issue.

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

And try to run `flutter doctor` again.

```
flutter doctor
```

---

If you do nothing, it's okay as long as you have installed the plugin. You can create project and working on it as usual (see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68878)).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in either android studio or flutter.
You can ignore it because everything still works as usual.